# pattern matching in RewriteMap text file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to do some pattern matching inside the rewrite text file using RewriteMap and it doesn't seem to work.  Below is the apache configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/apache1.log"
RewriteLogLevel 5
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
RewriteMap escape int:escape
RewriteMap sitelevel_external "txt:C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/html1/content/dam/redirect.txt"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%1} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${escape:%1} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond ${sitelevel_external:%1|NOT_FOUND} !NOT_FOUND
RewriteRule ^(.*) ${sitelevel_external:%1} [QSA,NC,NE,L,R=301,E=nocache:1]
```

The redirect.txt file contents are

```
^/delivery-delay.html$ http://www.yahoo.com // doesn't work
/delivery-delay.html$ http://www.yahoo.com  // doesn't work
/delivery-delay.html http://www.yahoo.com  // Works
```

If i use the URL http://localhost/delivery-delay.html, the redirection to yahoo only happens when the third rule is in there. Apache doesn't redirects and throws a 404 if i have the first two conditions.

[Apache Logs attached](http://txt.do/58u3w)

Comment: Looking at your configuration you have apache 2.2 right?

Comment: Yes it is Apache 2.2

Answer (score 0):

With a Standard Plain Text (`sitelevel_external`) file you cannot handle regular expression, the text file will be translated just in a key map.

`RewriteMap` handles different types of matches, but if you use a text file you can just look for an exact match. May be an [`External Rewriting Program`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) could fit your needs, but pay attention and keep it simple,

> "If this program hangs, it will cause Apache to hang when trying to
>   use the relevant rewrite rule."